# Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake

Tags: cmake, pip

I have the above error while running `pip install cmake` on alpine linux (WSL).

Full error:

```
/home/user# pip install cmake
Collecting cmake
  Using cached cmake-3.18.4.post1.tar.gz (28 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cmake
  Building wheel for cmake (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp4q90dnrm
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2d2lze1g/cmake_b52ab822a1764f9f9b60c93c8713e39b
  Complete output (9 lines):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-szooj3fd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 560, in setup
      cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-szooj3fd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 95, in __init__
      self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-szooj3fd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 81, in get_cmake_version
      raise SKBuildError(
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cmake
Failed to build cmake
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cmake which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing [cmake](https://cmake.org/).

For **alpine** linux - run:

```
apk add cmake
```

For **debian**/**ubuntu** - run:

```
apt-get install cmake
```

For **redhat**/**fedora**/**centos** - run:

```
yum install cmake
```