# Unable to install numpy through command prompt

Tags: python, numpy, libraries

I tried running the "pip3 install numpy" command and this was the output:

```
C:\Users\10art\Documents\hello>pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.26.3.tar.gz (15.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.7/15.7 MB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
        Downloading ninja-1.11.1.1.tar.gz (132 kB)
           ------------------------------------ 132.4/132.4 kB 601.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [15 lines of output]
        C:\Users\10art\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-559ptrj_\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:308: UserWarning: git archive did not support describe output
          warnings.warn("git archive did not support describe output")
        C:\Users\10art\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-559ptrj_\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:327: UserWarning: unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)
          warnings.warn("unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)")
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\10art\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-559ptrj_\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
            cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\10art\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-559ptrj_\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
            self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\10art\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-559ptrj_\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
            raise SKBuildError(msg) from err

        Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
      Failed to build ninja
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Saw someone having a similar problem and ran the following command: "pip install -U setuptools" but it did not change anything. Also tried updating python and repairing the install, but it had no effect. I have already installed python libraries and modules through wsl, but for some reason nothing is working on command prompt.

Comment: That's not numpy you are having problems installing - its ninja. Numpy does not depend on ninja so what you are doing is very unclear.

Comment: Just edited the output, did not paste it completely before

Comment: what command are you running? This is still halfway through the output.

Comment: C:\Users\10art\Documents\hello>pip3 install numpy 

That's the command. Double checked; that's the whole output

Comment: Your output is missing the command so it can't be the whole output.

Comment: Just added it, it's the command I mentioned in the previous comment. Went back, checked again and that's the full output

Comment: Well its something weird I guess. You really should try to describe a lot more context. What kind of python is this - a system installation or a virtual environment? You mentioned WSL - is this a wsl installation? Why do you think ninja is being built when numpy doesn't depend on ninja? It all about troubleshooting and trying things in cases like this. What version of Python you are using, what OS you are using...

Comment: Maybe try installing ninja first, by itself...

Comment: So it looks like you cannot build numpy from source ... so you do have some problem with your python build system. You can try downloading a wheel from pypi and skipping the whole building part. Numpy wheels: https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files Installing a wheel: [how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file) Not sure. I guess I'm confused too now. I apologize I was thinking `jinja` at first, not `ninja` - two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409168/problem-with-the-cmake-installation-aborting-build-cmake-executable-is-cmake), you might not have CMake. Since it looks like you're on Windows you can either go [download](https://cmake.org/) it or install it with

```
pip3 install cmake
```